# Adding different genes for same chromosomal regions to single line in Python

Tags: python, string, list, printing

Hi I am new to python and I have a file with chromosomal regions and corresponding genes of that region, I need to include different genes of same region in to one line like

```
chr12   10954262    10962540    chr12   10880241    11502235    100.0       ACACB   -
chr12   10954262    10962540    chr12   10880241    11502235    100.0       RAD52   -
chr12   10954262    10962540    chr12   10880241    11502235    100.0       RAD52   -
chr12   10954262    10962540    chr12   10880241    11502235    100.0       TAS2R8  -
chr12   10954262    10962540    chr12   10880241    11502235    100.0       TAS2R9  -
```

from the above lines I would like to have out put in single line (like below)with all gene names by the side of chromosomal region instead of multiple lines

```
chr12   10954262    10962540    chr12   10880241    11502235    100.0 ACACB, RAD52, RAD52, TAS2R8, TAS2R9
```

your help is highly appreciated.

Jyothi

Comment: OK; so what have you done so far? Can you open the file? Parse the data? Identify rows with the same region? Build the output? Write the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `filename` is a file containing containing the following:

```
chr12 10954262 10962540 chr12 10880241 11502235 100.0 ACACB -  
chr12 10954262 10962540 chr12 10880241 11502235 100.0 RAD52 -  
chr12 10954262 10962540 chr12 10880241 11502235 100.0 RAD52 -  
chr12 10954262 10962540 chr12 10880241 11502235 100.0 TAS2R8 - 
chr12 10954262 10962540 chr12 10880241 11502235 100.0 TAS2R9 - 
chr12 10977955 10999847 chr12 10880241 11502235 100.0 ERC1 -   
chr12 10977955 10999847 chr12 10880241 11502235 100.0 KCTD10 - 
chr12 10977955 10999847 chr12 10880241 11502235 100.0 MMAB -   
chr12 10977955 10999847 chr12 10880241 11502235 100.0 MYO1H -  
chr12 10977955 10999847 chr12 10880241 11502235 100.0 PRR4 -   
chr12 10977955 10999847 chr12 10880241 11502235 100.0 RAD52 -
```

**script.py**

```
from collections import defaultdict       
genes_dict = defaultdict(list)            
for line in open("filename",'r'):                            
    _,val,key = line[::-1].split(" ",2)   
    genes_dict[key[::-1]].append(val[::-1])           

for key in genes_dict:                    
    vals = ""                             
    for val in genes_dict[key]:           
        vals +=","+val               
    print key,vals.lstrip(",")
```

**output**

```
chr12 10977955 10999847 chr12 10880241 11502235 100.0 ERC1,KCTD10,MMAB,MYO1H,PRR4,RAD52
chr12 10954262 10962540 chr12 10880241 11502235 100.0 ACACB,RAD52,RAD52,TAS2R8,TAS2R9
```

Comment: @user3778087, Is this content also appended to the main file?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the code, how to do the same if have multiple regions in the same file like below, in my first question there is only one region with different gene names chr12 10977955 10999847 chr12 10880241 11502235 100.0  ERC1 -
chr12 10977955 10999847 chr12 10880241 11502235 100.0  KCTD10 -
chr12 10977955 10999847 chr12 10880241 11502235 100.0  MMAB -

Comment: yes, this is part of main file

Comment: @user3778087, I hope this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). It is more tolerant of variations in whitespace between the data columns, but may not work too well on very large input files due to the initial sorting requirements of `groupby()`.

```
from itertools import groupby

def keyfunc(row):
    # key is assumed to be all fields excluding the gene identifier
    return row[:-1]

rows = (row.split()[:-1] for row in open('chr_regions.txt'))
for k, g in groupby(sorted(rows, key=keyfunc), keyfunc):
    print '%s %s' % ('    '.join(k), ', '.join(x[-1] for x in g))
```

On input of this unsorted input (chr_regions.txt):

```
chr15   58887403    59042177    chr15   58887403    59042177    100.0       ADAM10  -
chr12   10954262    10962540    chr12   10880241    11502235    100.0       ACACB   -
chr12   10954262    10962540    chr12   10880241    11502235    100.0       RAD52   -
chr12   10954262    10962540    chr12   10880241    11502235    100.0       RAD52   -
chr21   43619799    43717354    chr21   43619799    43717354    100.0       ABCG1   -
chr12   10954262    10962540    chr12   10880241    11502235    100.0       TAS2R8  -
chr12   10954262    10962540    chr12   10880241    11502235    100.0       TAS2R9  -
chr21   43619799    43717354    chr21   43619799    43717354    100.0       ABCG2   -
```

Produces:

```
chr12    10954262    10962540    chr12    10880241    11502235    100.0 ACACB, RAD52, RAD52, TAS2R8, TAS2R9
chr15    58887403    59042177    chr15    58887403    59042177    100.0 ADAM10
chr21    43619799    43717354    chr21    43619799    43717354    100.0 ABCG1, ABCG2
```